# select() times out even though there is data in the buffer

Tags: c, select-function

This program is (I believe) a straight application of select() (on Debian for ARM).
XBEEDEVICE points to a serial port. The serial port exists and ic connected to a device.

Problem is, select() returns 0 even though there is data received. I temporarily commented out the last 'else' and the program prints TIMEOUT, then the string that was returned by the remote device.

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  int fd, c, res, n;
  struct termios oldtio, newtio;
  char buf[255] = {0};

  fd_set input;
  struct timeval timeout;

  // define timeout
  timeout.tv_sec = 5;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;

  fd = open( XBEEDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
  if( fd < 0 ){
    perror( XBEEDEVICE );
    return( -1 );
  }

  tcgetattr( fd, &oldtio ); /* save current port settings */
  bzero( &newtio, sizeof( newtio ));
  newtio.c_cflag = CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
  newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
  newtio.c_oflag = 0;

  /* set input mode (non-canonical, no echo,...) */
  newtio.c_lflag = 0;

  newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;   /* inter-character timer unused */
  newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 2;   /* blocking read until 2 chars received */

  tcflush( fd, TCIFLUSH );
  tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &newtio );

  // Sending +++ within 1 second sets the XBee into command mode
  printf( " Sending +++\n" );
  write( fd, "+++", 3 );

  n = select( fd, &input, NULL, NULL, &timeout );

  if( n < 0 )
    printf( "select() failed\n" );
  else if( n == 0 )
    printf( "TIMEOUT\n" );
  //else{
    res = read( fd, buf, 250 );
    buf[res] = 0;
    printf( "Received: %s\n", buf );
  //}
  tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio );

  return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: You should add more tags to your questions. Stackoverflow has a nice system to notify people about their favorite tags, so it will be easier for others to find your question if you add more relevant tags...

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize `input` to contain `fd`. This is done with `FD_ZERO` and `FD_SET` macros:

```
FD_ZERO(&input);
FD_SET(fd, &input);
```

This must be done done each time before `select` is called.

The first argument to `select` should be `fd+1`. It is the number of file descriptors in the range to be checked. Since the maximal (and only) descriptor number in the range is `fd`, and the minimum is always 0, the number in question is `fd+1`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try tonight. I have tried fd+1 (but not FD_ZERO() or FD_SET()) and that made no difference.

Comment: I have added the FD_ZERO() and FD_SET() calls and changed 'fd' to fd+1' and it now works. Thank you very much!